# use socket in android but throw exception

Tags: android, sockets

when use real phone, there are exception when I new socket in codes: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.90 (port 8000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
but when use emulator,there is no probelm.
I use AndroidAP and make my laptop connect to the phone, and in computer, 
"adb shell ping 192.168.43.90", result is OK, so I confused.

project is on 2.3, phone is 4.0

Comment: is there any involvement of SSL?

Comment: are you sure you are connected to the Internet ? or the mobile and the System you try to connect belongs to the same LAN ?

Comment: got it, because of the NOD32 firewall